# Why does Ethereum 2.0 aim for 64 shards?

Tags: eth-2.0, sharding

I was going through Ethereum 2.0 specs trying to look for an explanation for the number of shards (64) but I couldn't find any.

For example [here](https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/shard-chains/):

> Shard chains spread the network's load across 64 new chains.

Or the [formal specs](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/sharding/beacon-chain.md) where there are mentions of the initial number of shards (64) alongside a practical limit of 1024 shards but no explanation neither.

Why is it 64 ? Why not any other number ? Is there a rationale for this ?

Any argument or link to source would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the following, I guess the reasons are mostly based on performance and scalability.

The number of shards was redefined based on this [proposal](https://notes.ethereum.org/KbEyHiaSRQW_KS7dDK0OFw), which drastically simplifies communication between shards as they stated [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/10/31/eth2-quick-update-no-2/). Also, the block size was increased from from `16kB` to `128kB` in order to achieve the scalability of the previous proposal.

> To support this new proposal, the total shard count to start must be
> reduced from 1024 to the new estimate of 64, with the intention to
> scale up the number of shards over time (~10 years) as standard
> resources available to consumer laptops increases. The following are
> the primary reasons for the requisite reduction in total shards:
>
> - Each shard induces an attestation load on the network and beacon chain at each slot rather than at each epoch
> - Each committee must be of a minimum safe number of validators. If there are too many committees per epoch due to high shard count, then
>   there couldn’t possibly be enough 32-ETH validators to safely allocate
>   enough to each committee

**EDIT:**

From your comment, I've done some research since I'm curious too about why 64 shards and not other number.

First, from the [Ethereum 2.0 reddit AMA (Part 2)](https://docs.ethhub.io/other/ethereum-2.0-ama/#part-2) Justin Drake said (before changing from 1024 to 64 shard chains):

> Q: Why 1024 shards?
>
> JD: Because 2048 shards would be stressing the beacon chain and 512
> shards would be under-utilising the beacon chain.

From [Vitalik’s Annotated Ethereum 2.0 Spec](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/SkeyEI3xv#Misc)

> We plan to have 64 shards at the start. Having fewer shards would lead
> to insufficient scalability; having more would lead to two undesirable
> consequences:
>
> - Overhead of processing beacon chain blocks being too high
> - The minimum amount of ETH needed to reach a full-sized committee for every shard in every slot (now 32 ETH * 128 committee size * 64 shards
>   per slot * 32 slots per epoch = 8,388,608 ETH) to be too high; we’re
>   reasonably confident we can get 8.3m ETH staking, but getting 16.7m
>   ETH staking would be harder, and if we can’t get that much, the system
>   would be forced compromise by making cross-shard transactions take
>   longer.

Comment: While it it clearly a much better answer than the 2 previous ones, it's still fuzzy about the number 64... I mean it's obviously linked to performance and scalability, that's the whole point or shards, but 64 shard with a block size of `128KB` allows for `1.3-2.7 MB/s` bandwithd, but why is this bandwith range the target then ? I feel like that'd be the explanation for the number of shards, that's what I cannot find...

Comment: I'm not sure about the following, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess the capacity (`1.3-2.7 MB/s`) based on the slot time (`12 seconds`) can be calculated from the [overhead analysis](https://notes.ethereum.org/KbEyHiaSRQW_KS7dDK0OFw#Overhead-analysis) and shard block size.

Comment: Thank you for those references ! So it might also be related to the number of available validators.. which makes sense ! I'm still curious about the actual metric used to say "Because 2048 shards would be stressing the beacon chain and 512 shards would be under-utilising the beacon chain." It's just odd to say something so vague if there is a justification... not sure if he means in validators / in bandwidth or possibly both ? I am giving you the bounty anyway, thank you.